# Activity Field Injection Using Dagger 2

Tags: android, android-activity, dependency-injection, dagger-2

When using **Constructor Injection** with Dagger2, I can really see how the concept of dependency injection is implemented:

```
 public class Dependent {

     @Inject
     public Dependent(Dependency dependency) {
         // We're dependent on an instance of the Dependency class
         // but we don't care who provides it
     }

 }
```

But when it comes to an `Activity`, because Android is instantiating it for us, we need to use **Field Injection** to satisfy our dependencies. All of the examples I found online suggest something like this:

1. Create a `@Module` class to provide our dependency.
2. Create a `@Component` interface and call the generate builder to instantiate it. Most of the examples perform this in the `Application` class and save a reference as a member.
3. In our `Activity` - create our `@Inject` field, and in the `onCreate(..)` method, get a reference to the `Component` from our `Application` and initiate the injection.

My problem with this approach is that it doesn't *feel* loosely coupled, which is what we're trying to achieve.

```
 public class DependentActivity extends Activity {

     @Inject Dependency mDependency;

     public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);

         // We're dependent on an instance of dependency
         // but now we not only know who provides it,
         // we explicitly initiate the injection
     }

 }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initiate the injection, yes, but you don't have to have any knowledge about where it's coming from (meaning how the object is created, or how you get it). You could switch out your component classes that your Application gives you and your activity wouldn't change. You could switch out the module that provides your Dependent object and nothing in your activity would change. What this injection gives you is the ability to have your activity only deal with USING the injected object. Usually without dependency injection your activity would have to understand how to instantiate it, how to initialize it with whatever it needs, and also how to use it. This allows you to easily swap in and out components, change the way it's initialized, or whatever and your activity (ideally) wouldn't have to change a single thing.

Comment: So guess I pretty much got it. Thanks for answering, but I think what you said is a little optimistic: You *do* have knowledge of where the injection is coming from, at least on the surface, but the rest is true - you're not aware of the object creation and switching out components and modules is possible. I guess Activity DI with Dagger2 has a price of the Activity being aware of its injector. Oh well. Small price to pay.

Comment: "You could switch out your component classes that your Application gives you and your activity wouldn't change." absolutely correct